# Prove $||S*T||_{op}=||S||_{op}||T||_{op}$ if T: $R^n -> R^n $is an isometry

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Prove $||S*T||_{op}=||S||_{op}||T||_{op}$, if T: $R^n -> R^n $ is an isometry, that is $||T(x)||=||x||$ for all $x \in R^n$

Define $||T||_{op}=sup_{||x||=1}||T(x)|| $

Attempt: $||S*T||_{op}\le||S||_{op}||T||_{op}=||S||_{op}$
I'm struggling to prove the inequality in the other direction. Is this the right route to go or is there something simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $||S*T||_{op}\le||S||_{op}$ replace  $T$ by $T^{-1}$ (permissible since $T^{-1}$ is also an isometry)  and replace $S$ by $S*T$. You get $\|S\|_{op}=\|(S*T)*T^{-1})\|_{op} \leq \|S*T\|_{op}$